# Facebook posts notification feed application

Tags: notification, facebook, web-feed

Is there any app for ubuntu that for the posts I enable 'Turn on notifications for this post' can show me live in a nice way the messages/replies etc like a feed/popup etc?

Answer (score 0):

None like that have been published by Facebook.